# Is this reverse loop is correct in C?

Tags: c, for-loop

Sometimes in javascript you can see reverse loop like this one :

```
for ( let i =10; i--;) { ... }
```

where `i` get values from 9 to zero inside the loop.
the  boolean evaluation of `i--`  is true when `i` > 0,
then the value of `(i-1)` go inside the loop,
the third argument stay empty as the decrementation of `i` is allready done before.

in C this should be: (?)

```
for (int i =10; i--;) { ... }
```

I'm just wondering if this could be accepted (and working) in C language?

I just want to know if it can be done or not and give an identical result to this for loop:

```
for (int i =9; i>=0 ;i--) { ... }
```

Comment: `for (int i=10; i--;)` is correct and will do the same as the js version. However, it is better to write the loop in a more readable form: `for (int i=9; i>=0; i--)`

Comment: @kaylum I don't have a c compiler at disposal

Comment: You could also use the [`-->` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c) ;)

Comment: Yes, it is correct. it is also the best way to reverse-index an array. (whithout needing the ugly ssize_t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your hypothetical code is valid C and will work as intended. However, beware of the slight variant

```
for (unsigned int i = 10; i >= 0; i--) { ... }
```

This is an infinite loop, because an unsigned int cannot be *less* than zero. JavaScript does not have unsigned types so this can't happen there.

Why would anyone ever write that? Well, suppose you need to crunch a string backwards for some reason, you might naturally write

```
for (size_t i = strlen(s); i >= 0; i--) { ... use s[i] ... }
```

but, whoops, size_t is unsigned.

Comment: I thought you were referring to `for (int i =10; i--; )`. That, I do use. Some people have problems with it, but it's a common idiom. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i =9; i>=0 ;i--) 
{ ... }
```

Comment: @MisterJojo, why not?

Comment: I just want to know if this unnusal loop syntax is correct or not.